# how to have a chart from only one page of multi-sheet .ods file?

Tags: linux, libreoffice, spreadsheet, graph

I downloaded [Visa stats](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/2015_consulates_schengen_visa_stats_en.xlsx) from EU site which were unfortunately in .xlsx (MS-Excel) format. I used calligrasheets to transform the .xlsx to .ods sheet and was able to open the same in libreoffice. The converted file can be downloaded from [here](https://dropfile.to/Sks88Py) . Now if you see the file, you will see it is a multi-sheet file.

Now I'm trying to get sense of this data, how can I make a chart so I can see what the stats. are telling me of each sheet ? I want to have individual charts of each page.

The output would be if this can be done, then potentially any multi-sheet .ods file would become chart-friendly.

Any possibilities anyone ?